# What is a 'notch' in image processing?

Tags: image-processing, filters, filter-design, filtering

I cannot find out what does "notch" means in image processing? 
We have selective filters that one of the best of them is *Notch* filters. but what does the concept of "Notch"? why they are called "notch" filters?

Comment: Notch filter which rejects the certain range of frequencies in predefined neighborhoods about a center frequency.. In the image

Answer (score 1):

In standard 1D signal processing, [notch filters](http://www.dspguide.com/ch19/3.htm) are filters that try to remove one specific frequency, and pass all others.

I say "try to" because this is not usually achievable, but it comes close.

Steve W. Smiths's *DSP Guide* has a nice plot (Figure 19.6b below) that shows the frequency response of such filters.

In image processing, it will be the same thing, but instead of a 1D filter it'll be a 2D filter probably comprised of two 1D notch filters --- one in each image direction.

[image]

Comment: What is the difference between a bandreject filter and notch filter, especially in image processing.

Comment: @maia Ask that as a question!   Notch == single frequency; band == range of frequencies.